# SQL Server Implicit convert to varchar vs bigint

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, implicit-conversion

In summary, is that a slightly perfomance improvement to varchar instead of bigint.

For example, I have a two table like this as below

**Item**

```
ID bigint PK;
item_code varchar(256);
```

**SalesItem**

```
ID bigint PK;
item_id varchar(256);
```

Please take note that `item_id` is not a foreign key and due to some special case `item_id` is allowed to be `varchar(256)`;

I tried a SQL statement like this

```
Select SalesItem.item_id
from SalesItem
left join Item on SalesItem.item_id = Item.id
```

That causes an implicit conversion that SQL Server is trying to convert varchar into int and the performance is worst.

Somehow, we changed the sql into below:

```
Select SalesItem.item_id
from SalesItem
left join Item on SalesItem.item_id = convert(varchar(256), Item.id)
```

Well the performance is outstanding, decreased by nearly 70%-80%

Just curios about is that the sequences on 'ON' matter? and which should I convert it?

Instead of I convert to `varchar(256)` on `item.id` is that better that I convert to `bigint` on `salesitem.item_id`?

For eg:

```
Select SalesItem.item_id
from SalesItem
left join Item on Item.id = convert(bigint, SalesItem.item_id)
```

Please take note that above sql is just a sample.

Comment: I think, this is what you have to try yourself like you did before and see the Performance issue. You have all the required tables and enough data to see the difference. Just like before (you changed to Varchar) now change it to bigint and see. And, consider the another thing too, about indexing on Join Column.

Comment: @N.p Subedi Ya, thanks for advice. I tested convert to main table is much more faster tough from 3 minutes to fews second
The correct sql will be [Select salesitem.item_id from SalesItem left join Item on Item.id = convert(bigint, Salesitem.item_id)] instead i convert item.id to varchar(256), it is much faster i convert salesitem.item_id to bigint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general comparing two numbers will do better than comparing two strings.

Saying that in your case, there is a slight chance that the select might fail when you convert the SalesItem.item_id to bigint, as it is stored as the varchar in the first place, it might have some characters  as well, which cannot be converted to Integer.

Comment: Tested, its is definitely faster if i convert it to a big int.